# How to do an exclusive or (XOR) for void functions in openCV C++?

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++, tracking, cascade-classifier

I have a project that detects head detection using `CascadeClassifer` and tracking using Tracker lib in openCV. How to do an exclusive or(XOR) of void function? because I separated the detection from the tracking using void function. how will do that it will detects the head then it will start to track and if it starts tracking the detection will stop?

Comment: Please consider rewriting this question, native English speakers cannot readily understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `void CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale(const Mat& image, vector<Rect>& objects, double scaleFactor=1.1, int minNeighbors=3, int flags=0, Size minSize=Size(), Size maxSize=Size())` to find objects in the image then you do not need to XOR the *void* value. The result of the detection is found in `vector<Rect>& objects`. The detection was successful if the vector conatins any Rectangles.
If something is detected then you want the detection to stop and the result should be tracked. Doing an XOR like `if(detection^tracking)` won't help you, because

- you need to compute the detection anyway (to get a result for comparison)
- you do not know, if a detection or a tracking should be done, because it will be true either way.

I suggest that you add a boolean variable `bool foundRectangle` to your class, which gets toggled btween true and false. It is false if you need a detection and is true if the detection found at least one rectangle, which should be tracked.

```
if(foundRectangle){
    //track();
}
else {
    //detect();
}
```